# How to create artifical life forms?

Tags: biology, life

Would it be possible to create artificial life forms? What are some possible ways to accomplish this if it's possible? What kind of materials could their organs and blood be made of? What would be some possible ways they can reproduce? And once these lifeforms were created would they be able to evolve? An alien race much more advanced than humanity wants to create intelligent artificial life forms to inhabit a planet they created.

Comment: "Possible?" If you mean like a new mouse-sized creature, with current technology, no. If you mean with more advanced technology, it might be useful to explain the level of technology this world possesses.

Comment: Yes I mean with more advanced technology than humans, In my mind i'm thinking of an alien race that wants to create artificial life forms and an artificial planet for them to live on.

Comment: An intriguing question but far too broad to effectively answer as it stands. Do you have a specific hypothetical scenario in mind, or is your curiosity really this open-ended?

Comment: Now let's assume they have been created and were placed on the planet created for them do you think they might worship their creators?

Comment: @NexTerren why not actually, take cell place DNA, good for me, ready to go. Needs lot of knowledge trough, not our current level sure. So I would ask OP to define what means create in this case. For worshiping place another question, short answer yes the can - depends on knowledge of creators.

Comment: @Stephanie Even if the creatures (using the word in its correct sense) were placed on a planet created for them, the likelihood of them worshipping their creators is vanishing small. They might be even if aware of their origins. Imagine how we'd react if aliens arrived and proclaimed we were their creations.

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be possible to create artificial life forms?

You cannot prove a negative. So the answer is: "yes".

> What are some possible ways to accomplish this if it's possible?

This is **much** too broad to answer. I will have to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_life).

> What kind of materials could their organs...

Anything.

> ...and blood be made of?

who says they must use blood?

> What would be some possible ways they can reproduce?

Anything.

> And once these lifeforms were created would they be able to evolve?

Depending on how they are created, yes.

Without the intention to sound terse... what are you actually looking for? Because right now you have just thrown out a very broad question without any kind of delimiters. It will help us to answer if you say what you need for your world/story.

But if you just ask us to list **every possible option** or to scratch-build your artificial life, you will not get very detailed answers beyond "Yeah, it's possible, in many ways". Limit your question and tell us what it is you are looking for in better detail please.

Comment: I like your answer, I know it is a very broad question, I didn't know "anything" would work for blood, organs etc

Comment: @Stephanie You ask about artificial life as if it is "almost like current life, but not quiet". Either you should specify that this is what you are looking for; that this is the delimiter you want...t hat the artificial life should be **almost** like life as we know it, only not quite. Or you should free yourself of that notion and start thinking about what you mean with "life". Because as long as you keep the question this enormously broad, the answers will be correspondingly broad as well. So what are you looking for, really?

Comment: Yes they are artificial, almost like "life" as we know it ,but do everything that natural evolved species do.

Comment: @Stephanie do they ready to wait millions of millions of years ? Which level they are creating. I personally suggest you to stick with exterior of them, which you wish them to be. They just wished them and created them to look like they wished them to be. And theeen, after some time strange things begins to happened ....  Oblivious, when aliens focusing only on exterior they may make "mistakes", with consequences.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely upon your definition of life, a factory that builds robots that build factories could be life in the sense that these factories consume resources and reproduce, you can even kill them in the sense that sufficient damage will make them incapable of functioning.

Replication errors in the factory/robot programming might cause these factories to evolve, maybe by chance two factories will inadvertently work together to construct a third. Maybe these cooperative factories build faster than their more independent peers. Maybe factories with two or more parents are fitter by inheriting beneficial traits from more of the factory “gene pool” than single parent factories.

Maybe a factory will evolve to mine resources from other factories, maybe these other factories will evolve defences against being mined for resources, maybe some factories become more intelligent/adaptable in order to better compete in the factory ecosystem.

Maybe one day a factory will post a message to a location their global communications network reserved for speculating upon hypothetical scenarios and in this particular hypothesis it's speculated that maybe intelligent life could evolve from complex chemical reactions...

Its peers scoff at the idea, it could never happen they say, chemical reactions are too chaotic to ever be the basis of such sophisticated mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

The chances are they'd take an existing species and modify to be intelligent. For example, if their newly created planet had higher gravity they would chose a quadruped species and alter its neurology to make it intelligent. A better choice might be a hexapod species because at least one pair of limbs could be adapted to become arms.

The main reason why they would populate a created planet with artificial intelligent life is ethical and moral objections to using members of their own species.

If the creatures have a fully functional genome and they can reproduce they will evolve. Just remember this will take a long time. Also, if the creatures were created *de novo* and without culture, language or technology it could be a long wait before they develop a technical civilisation. Humans evolved about one hundred thousand years ago and it's taken us that long to arrive at the stage of being able to invent internet dating sites. Ah! The price of progress.

Craig Venter was made to make an artificial genome for a bacterium. So your advanced aliens should be able to do similar for intelligent organisms. This could involve building their genome from scratch, but using what would to them known structures and organisation of the genetic material to produce an intelligent organism, or, as I suggested, taking the genome of an existing organism and modifying it for intelligence.

The technical side of making artificial life is the easy bit. Why they are doing it is the real challenge. Also what they expect to get out of it. And when, this could be a very, very long trial.